# How to append a specific string according to each value in a string pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, string

Let's take these sample dataframes :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id':['1','2','3','4','5'], 'Value':[9,8,7,6,5]})

  Id  Value
0  1      9
1  2      8
2  3      7
3  4      6
4  5      5

df_name = pd.DataFrame({'Id':['1','2','4'], 'Name':['Andrew','Jason','John']})

  Id    Name
0  1  Andrew
1  2   Jason
2  4    John
```

I would like to add in the Id column of df the Name of the person (obtainable  in df_name) if it exists, in brackets. I know how to do this with a for loop over the Id column of df but it is inefficient with large dataframes. Do you know please a better way do to this ?

Expected output :

```
           Id  Value
0  1 (Andrew)      9
1   2 (Jason)      8
2           3      7
3    4 (John)      6
4           5      5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for match values, add `()` and replace non matche values by original column in [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['Id'] = ((df['Id'] + ' (' + df['Id'].map(df_name.set_index('Id')['Name']) + ')')
               .fillna(df['Id']))
print (df)
           Id  Value
0  1 (Andrew)      9
1   2 (Jason)      8
2           3      7
3    4 (John)      6
4           5      5
```